# Fluentd record with source filename parts

Tags: fluentd

I'm using fluentd on a server to export logs.

My configuration uses something like this to capture several log files:

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /my/path/to/file/*/*.log
</source>
```

The different files are tracked properly, however, I have one more feature needed:

The two wildcards parts of the path should be added to the record as well (let's call them `directory` and `filename`).

If the `in_tail` plugin would add the filename to the record, I could write a formatter to split and edit.

Anything that I'm missing or rewriting `in_tail` to my heart wishes is the best way to go?

Answer (score 1):

So, yes. Extending `in_tail` is the way to go.

I've written a new plugin that inherits from `NewTailInput` and uses a slightly different `parse_singleline` and `parse_multilines` to add the path to the record.

Much better than expected.

---

Update 6/3/2020:
I've dug up the code, this was the least Ruby I could muster to solve the problem.
Customize `convert_line_to_event_with_path_names` for your needs to add custom data to the records.

```
module Fluent
  class DirParsingTailInput < NewTailInput
    Plugin.register_input('dir_parsing_tail', self)

    def initialize
      super
    end


    def receive_lines(lines, tail_watcher)
      es = @receive_handler.call(lines, tail_watcher)
      unless es.empty?
        tag = if @tag_prefix || @tag_suffix
                @tag_prefix + tail_watcher.tag + @tag_suffix
              else
                @tag
              end
        begin
          router.emit_stream(tag, es)
        rescue
          # ignore errors. Engine shows logs and backtraces.
        end
      end
    end

    def convert_line_to_event_with_path_names(line, es, path)
      begin
        directory = File.basename(File.dirname(path))
        filename = File.basename(path, ".*")
        line.chomp!  # remove \n
        @parser.parse(line) { |time, record|
          if time && record
            if directory != "logs"
              record["parent"] = directory
              record["child"] = filename
            else
              record["parent"] = filename
            end 
            es.add(time, record)
          else
            log.warn "pattern not match: #{line.inspect}"
          end
        }
      rescue => e
        log.warn line.dump, :error => e.to_s
        log.debug_backtrace(e.backtrace)
      end
    end

    def parse_singleline(lines, tail_watcher)
      es = MultiEventStream.new
      lines.each { |line|
        convert_line_to_event_with_path_names(line, es, tail_watcher.path)
      }
      es
    end

    def parse_multilines(lines, tail_watcher)
      lb = tail_watcher.line_buffer
      es = MultiEventStream.new
      if @parser.has_firstline?
        lines.each { |line|
          if @parser.firstline?(line)
            if lb
              convert_line_to_event_with_path_names(lb, es, tail_watcher.path)
            end
            lb = line
          else
            if lb.nil?
              log.warn "got incomplete line before first line from #{tail_watcher.path}: #{line.inspect}"
            else
              lb << line
            end
          end
        }
      else
        lb ||= ''
        lines.each do |line|
          lb << line
          @parser.parse(lb) { |time, record|
            if time && record
              convert_line_to_event_with_path_names(lb, es, tail_watcher.path)
              lb = ''
            end
          }
        end
      end
      tail_watcher.line_buffer = lb
      es
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about this

Comment: @yulkes I realize this is ancient, but could you share some code of how you accomplished this?

Comment: @eirikir I updated the post, managed to dig up the old code. I hope it helps you!